# Preserving creation date of a file

Tags: windows-10, filesystems

Copying files across the same system does not change their creation time (excluding folders for reasons unknown to me). I presume it will be reset when connecting hard drive to different PC.

Is there a way to permanently preserve them? Or the only way is to set unique name (date_filename, for example).

Comment: hi, see if it's helpful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20255368/how-to-preserve-files-original-creation-date

Comment: @GloriaGu files have proper creation time when copying. I'm more interested how to keep them when switching computers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The creation time is stored on the disk in the file-table and will not change
when the disk is moved to another computer.

Read in wikipedia about [NTFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS).

Comment: Ok, so problem does not exist. HDD (SSD probably too) seems to be one whole "ecosystem". I'm not sure why directory creation time gets reset even while copying, but it is not an issue for me, i want to preserve file creation time.